# Custom claims with Rusts openidconnect crate

Tags: rust, openid-connect

I'm using the [openidconnect crate](https://docs.rs/openidconnect/latest/openidconnect/index.html) to talk to a Zitadel instance. The basic authentication flow works fine so far, but now I need to return additional claims from Zitadel. The `openidconnect::CoreClient` is defined like this:

```
pub type CoreClient = Client<
    EmptyAdditionalClaims,
    CoreAuthDisplay,
    CoreGenderClaim,
    CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm,
    CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm,
    CoreJsonWebKeyType,
    CoreJsonWebKeyUse,
    CoreJsonWebKey,
    CoreAuthPrompt,
    StandardErrorResponse<CoreErrorResponseType>,
    CoreTokenResponse,
    CoreTokenType,
    CoreTokenIntrospectionResponse,
    CoreRevocableToken,
    CoreRevocationErrorResponse,
>;
```

I would like to replace the `EmptyAdditionalClaims` with my own definition which looks like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyClaims {
    # todo ...
}

impl AdditionalClaims for MyClaims {}
```

My own client is copy & paste from the `CoreClient` with the first parameter replaced:

```
pub type MyClient = Client<
    MyClaims,
    #  copy & paste from above
    #  ...
>;
```

I end up with the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `StandardTokenResponse<IdTokenFields<EmptyAdditionalClaims, EmptyExtraTokenFields, CoreGenderClaim, CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm, CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm, CoreJsonWebKeyType>, BasicTokenType>: openidconnect::TokenResponse<MyClaims, CoreGenderClaim, CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm, CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm, CoreJsonWebKeyType, BasicTokenType>` is not satisfied
   --> app/src/auth.rs:92:17
    |
92  |     pub client: MyClient,
    |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `openidconnect::TokenResponse<MyClaims, CoreGenderClaim, CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm, CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm, CoreJsonWebKeyType, BasicTokenType>` is not implemented for `StandardTokenResponse<IdTokenFields<EmptyAdditionalClaims, EmptyExtraTokenFields, CoreGenderClaim, CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm, CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm, CoreJsonWebKeyType>, BasicTokenType>`
    |
    = help: the trait `openidconnect::TokenResponse<AC, GC, JE, JS, JT, TT>` is implemented for `StandardTokenResponse<IdTokenFields<AC, EF, GC, JE, JS, JT>, TT>`
note: required by a bound in `openidconnect::Client`
   --> /home/domma/development/axum-zitadell-demo/openidconnect-rs/src/lib.rs:794:9
    |
794 |     TR: TokenResponse<AC, GC, JE, JS, JT, TT>,
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Client`
```

I understand that some trait bound is not satisfied, but I don't get why. This kind of extension point seems to be a default pattern in openidconnect-rs, but the example only show its usage in other cases.

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing or show me a working example on how to customize the client with custom claims?

Answer (score 1):

In order to support custom claims you need to replace the `CoreTokenResponse` as well, as it also contains a reference to the additional claims.

My working solution:

```
pub type MyClient = Client<
        MyAdditionalClaims, // <- replace here
        CoreAuthDisplay,
        CoreGenderClaim,
        CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm,
        CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm,
        CoreJsonWebKeyType,
        CoreJsonWebKeyUse,
        CoreJsonWebKey,
        CoreAuthPrompt,
        StandardErrorResponse<CoreErrorResponseType>,
        MyTokenResponse, // <- replace here
        CoreTokenType,
        CoreTokenIntrospectionResponse,
        CoreRevocableToken,
        CoreRevocationErrorResponse,
    >;

    pub type BexioTokenResponse = StandardTokenResponse<
        MyIdTokenFields, // <- replace here
        CoreTokenType
    >;

    pub type BexioIdTokenFields = IdTokenFields<
        MyAdditionalClaims, // <- replace here
        EmptyExtraTokenFields,
        CoreGenderClaim,
        CoreJweContentEncryptionAlgorithm,
        CoreJwsSigningAlgorithm,
        CoreJsonWebKeyType,
    >;

    #[derive(Clone, Debug, Default, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize)]
    pub struct MyAdditionalClaims {
        // Claims here
    }

    impl AdditionalClaims for MyAdditionalClaims {}
```